# Relationship navigation in WCF Data Service with custom (object) data source

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I have 3 levels of hierarchy in my data:
DepartmentList -> EmployeeCollection -> Employee

Basically, there are a number departments, each containing a number of employees.

Here is my source code:

```
public class DataService : DataService<Departments>


public class Departments
    {
        private List<Department> _deptCollection;

        public IQueryable<Department> DeptCollection { get { return this._deptCollection.AsQueryable(); } }

...
...
    }

[DataServiceKey("DepartmentId")]
public class Department
{
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }

    private IList<EmployeeBase> _employees { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<EmployeeBase> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees.AsQueryable(); }
    }

    ...
}


[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class EmployeeBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to browse the DataService, I get the following error:

> The server encountered an error
>   processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'On data context type
>   'Departments', there is a top
>   IQueryable property 'DeptCollection'
>   whose element type is not an entity
>   type. Make sure that the IQueryable
>   property is of entity type or specify
>   the IgnoreProperties attribute on the
>   data context type to ignore this
>   property.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.ReflectionServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2
>   knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes,
>   IDictionary`2 entitySets) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
>   at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at
>   SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object
>   , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&
>   outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

I think I need to implement the relationship navigation here, which an entity data model does by itself for a SQL Source. But I'm not too sure. Any pointers would be very helpful.
Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key property on an entity class must be a property. In your case the Department.DepartmentId is a field. Turn it into a property.
One other note. There's no need to return IQueryable from the Department.Employees, only IEnumerable will be used anyway (it doesn't hurt though).
You will need an IQueryable property on your Departments class for this to work. Each entity must have its own top-level entity set.

Comment: @Vitek Karas MSFT: Converted Department.DepartmentId into a property and Departments.DeptCollection is an IQueryable property. Getting a different error this time.
`The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The property 'Employees' on type 'Microsoft.Eureka.Data.Department' is not a valid property. Properties whose types are collection of primitives or complex types are not supported.'. See server logs for more details.`

Comment: Also, regarding IQueryable Department.Employees, will I be able to fire a query on Department.Employees, if it is IEnumerable instead of IQueryable? What I am basically looking for is: `http://localhost/DataService.svc/DeptCollection('Dept01')/Employees`.

Comment: The new error you get basically means that the Employees property is not recognized as a list of entities, so the EmployessBase is not recognizes as entity. Class is recognized as entity if it has key property (seems you have that) and if there's a public IQueryable<ThatClass> property on the context class.

Comment: Navigation properties (that is what the Department.Employess property is called) can be queried even if they are just IEnumerable. This is because the query always starts with the entity set (DeptCollection in your sample) which is IQueryable. And so the rest of that query runs with that IQueryable.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks Vitek. Two changes and it's working the way I wanted. 1. Added `public IQueryable<EmployeeBase>` property in `Departments` class, which is the context class for me. 2. Added `public DepartmentId` property in `EmployeeBase` to link the EmployeeBase instance with Department. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Vitek: One more question, though. After I created `public IQueryable<EmployeeBase> Employees` property in my context class, it appears as a collection when I browse my service, `http://localhost/DataService.svc/`, which is misleading, because Employees collection doesn't exist at the root level. I get 404 Not Found error when I try to access it with the URI `http://localhost/DataService.svc/Employees`. And if I remove the EntityAccessRule for it, then it doesn't work at all; meaning even `http://localhost/DataService.svc/DeptCollection('P1234')/Employees` URI doesn't work. Can this be fixed?